# How do I solve these errors with npm install and sudo npm install -g harp?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, harp

I was trying to install Node.js, Grunt and Harp so I downloaded Node.js and then I wrote in the terminal this (note: I also had Homebrew):
node -v

```
npm update -g npm
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

After that I installed Bootstrap files and I wrote (always from the terminal) I wrote:

```
npm install
```

the terminal returned this:

```
[bash-3.2# npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Bimbi/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Bimbi/package.json'
npm WARN Bimbi No description
npm WARN Bimbi No repository field.
npm WARN Bimbi No README data
npm WARN Bimbi No license field.

up to date in 0.05s
```

After that I ran these commands to update Ruby, install bundler and some dependencies:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm list known
rvm install ruby-2.4.2
ruby -v
rvm use ruby-2.4.2 —default
gem install bundler
bundler -v
gem init
bundle install
gem install Jekyll bundler
```

then I tried to install harp:

```
sudo npm install -g harp
```

the terminal returned this:

```
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
/usr/local/bin/harp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/harp/bin/harp
+ harp@0.25.0
updated 1 package in 9.639s
```

after this message I ran:

```
harp -V
```

the console returned:

Comment: What did the console return? (you seem to have missed off part of your question) Also, why did you install harp using `sudo`?